# openAtLogin doesn't work when the Electron application is requireAdministrator

Tags: javascript, electron

I build my Electron applicaiton with requireAdministrator execution level, that my application will run as administrator by default. And my app also set with openAtLogin to startup with system boots:

```js
app.setLoginItemSettings({ openAtLogin: true, })
```

but I found it didn't startup automatically when system starts. If I remove the requireAdministrator, it can startup automatically on system starts. Anyone know how to fix this issue for Administrator execution level app?